# Opposite of "When things go south"

Tags: idioms

I just wonder about this idiom.

> When things go south, ...

Can I express the opposite way with

> When things go north, ...

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't.

There is no opposite matching phrase to "when things go south", there are of course many phrases that mean going well and to plan.

"going south" means that everything is going wrong, your plan is failing.

Suitable opposites would be:

- [coming up trumps](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-come-up-trumps/)
- [coming up roses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coming%20up%20roses)
- [all grand](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grand_1)

Comment: I agree, and a few candidates might include: _When things are [looking up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/looking+up), when things are getting better, when things are [on the rebound](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+rebound), when things are [on the mend](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+mend)_, or _when [everything is coming up roses](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/everything%27s+coming+up+roses)_.

Comment: _on the mend_ means things were broken but are getting better, so not really suitable. Looking up means improving so not correct. On the rebound also means recovering. So coming up roses is the only suitable one.

Comment: Whether or not one of those phrases is "suitable" depends on the context. I might ask a friend, "How are things going with your new girlfriend?" and he might reply, "Oh, things are going south." Assume things are going better one week later, when I ask the question again. In that case, the reply, "Things are on the mend" might be entirely appropriate. So I agree that "coming up roses" may be the most general purpose of the ones I listed, but not quite so sure I'd call it "the only suitable one."

Comment: The phrases I "objected to" all presume something was wrong which is now getting better. "going south" doesn't presume things were going excellent before starting to go wrong.  I don't know who is right or wrong now, but just adding "why" clarification.

Comment: RE: _I don't know who is right or wrong now_ – I would say we're both right, and we are both just giving clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

[*When all goes well*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+hope+all+goes+well) is a fitting and common expression.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there *is*, at least metaphorically, an opposite expression—although it's phrased and used slightly differently.

At first, things **went south**, but then [**I found my true north**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/find+true+north):

> To find or proceed on the correct course or in the right direction. A reference to finding the position of the North Pole (e.g., by compass or by locating a pole star) so as to navigate properly. *I would strongly advise that you seek professional legal counsel to find true north in your case against the state.*

Although it uses some odd capitalization, look at the article ["Introducing: Discover Your True North"](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/bill-george/introducing-discover-your_b_7965680.html) (which was written by the author of a similarly named book).