# Does "be looking up" mean improving "so not correct"?

Tags: meaning

this post (https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/169966) says

> Looking up means improving so not correct

cambridge (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/look-up?q=looking+up) gives

> to become better

I cannot get the meaning of "so not correct" in this example.

> Our financial situation is looking up at last.

Is there some special situation where "Looking up means improving so not correct", if yes, what is that?

Comment: In the comment you link to, there should be a comma after 'up'. "So not correct" is not part of the meaning of 'looking up".

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. In context, it seems the *reason* "looking up" isn't "correct" is that it refers to a "dynamic" state (wherein things are ***getting** better*, which isn't exactly the opposite of the "static" state where things ***have gone south***).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Shouldn't the comma be added after 'improving'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @CJDennis misunderstanding of what? what is the correct one?

Comment: "Looking up" means "improving", so [what the other person said is] not correct.